# Volt/mongodb query for list of unique fields?

Tags: mongodb, querying, voltrb

In Volt: say I have a bunch of `people` with (nonunique) `job_title` fields, is there a way to query for a list of all existing job titles?

e.g. if I have:

```
{name: 'sam', job_title: 'boss' },
{name: 'alex', job_title: 'lieutenant' },
{name: 'cal', job_title: 'underling' },
{name: 'morgan', job_title: 'underling' },
{name: 'harper', job_title: 'underling' }
```

I would use `store.`***`???`*** to get `['boss', 'lieutenant', 'underling']`, or similar? Is there a way to do this? Tried something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297905/mongodb-php-getting-fields-unique-values), but got `undefined method 'group'`.

Comment: `db.collection.distinct('job_title')`

Comment: Hadn't seen that type of query yet; thanks! Looks like it hasn't been implemented in Volt, though :-/